# creating an ebook, best way to go about it?

Tags: c#

So lets say I have a word document. It is a training manual. I wanna create an ebook out of this. But the thing is, it needs to have an interactive session. For example, the table of contents will have clickable links that follow to that specific part of the chapter.

So I am at a loss on how to approach this. Should I get my friend to modify the word document so that it is like "html"

```
[title linkto:keyword] Chapter 1 [/title]
```

And then have a table of keywords for easy look ups?

Also will a Rich Textbox be enough to handle this (links, formatting, etc etc)

Alternative approach:
Scan through word document. Have each "page" in the word document as a seperate field entry  in my db. Make sense?

Comment: Make a PDF from it. Many eBooks come as PDFs, and there are many doc to PDF converters out there. I don't really see this as a programming question.

Comment: I still need it to be interactive though. So think wikipedia. Certain keywords lead you to different sections.

Comment: Do you want to create an ebook programatically from your code, or manually? If you mean the latter, this is a good question for Super User.

Comment: @Oded and @masfenix: From past experience, PDF allows tables of contents with clickable links.

Comment: well, I have it as a word document right now. I need to make a little program with "next", "back" buttons, as well as a "bookmark" feature. And like I said, clickable links. so I already have the content, I just need to figure out how to design the software for it.

Comment: @Maxim Z. - Well aware of that, which is why I suggested PDF in the first place.

Comment: @Oded awesome. just wanted to make sure masfenix knew that too.

Comment: @masfenix - You need to look at PDF software. I believe all you need can be done in word and converted with something like PDF Creator to the kind of eBook you want.

Comment: @Maxim Z. - seeing as the requirement is to convert a word document to an eBook, I would say this question belongs on superuser.com, not here.

Comment: @masfenix Here's my recommendation: don't reinvent the wheel. From what it sounds like, you want to create your own Adobe Reader (or one of the many similar applications). In my opinion, that's not a good use of time, as there's already a great product out there with a huge codebase. If you have any *major* problems with what Reader offers, you can write your own, but I still discourage it. As for ebook format, you should use PDF, because almost everyone can read a PDF nowadays and it supports all the functions you're looking for. Good luck! :)

Comment: @Oded that's true, but he also mentioned in a comment above that he wants to "make a little program with 'next', 'back' buttons, as well as a 'bookmark' feature. And like I said, clickable links." As I said in my above comment, I don't think it's good to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @Maxim Z. - fair enough, but like yourself, I see this as an exercise in reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Alright guys, thankyou. so how do i accept an answer here when there are no answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not reinvent the wheel.

PDFs already do everything you want and they are one of the most used formats for eBooks. They are widely supported - there are tools for converting from word documents, PDF authoring and of course readers.

Answer (score 1):

Office 2007 (not sure about the 2003 one) allows you to insert headers within your document. There is an option that automatically builds the index table for you. If you then save the document as a PDF, the names of the chapters in the index page become hyperlinks. Once you click on the chapter name, you are immediately taken to the page where that chapter begins.